# Referring to a FORM and Control in a WITH Trough a Public function (.NET)

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to use a variable Form name and variable DataGridView (DGV) name in a public function (in a with/end with). Is it possible to do it?

The goal of the function is quite simple: if the Field in the DataGridView is empty give the function object a NULL value and if not give the function object the value from the DGV Field.

Everything else is working A1 beside the variable form name and DGV Name

Here's my Function

```
Public Function FILLORNULLFIELDFROMDATATABLE(DGV_FIELD As String, FORM_NAME As String, DGV_NAME As String) As Object

    With FORM_NAME.DGV_NAME.CurrentRow
        If IsDBNull(.Cells(DGV_FIELD).Value) Then
            FILLORNULLFIELDFROMDATATABLE = Nothing
        Else
            FILLORNULLFIELDFROMDATATABLE = .Cells(DGV_FIELD).Value
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine help me with this one, here's how we solved it :

```
 Public Function FILLORNULLFIELDFROMDATATABLE(ByVal Ligne As DataGridViewRow, DGV_FIELD As String) As Object

    If IsDBNull(Ligne.Cells(DGV_FIELD).Value) Then
        FILLORNULLFIELDFROMDATATABLE = Nothing
    Else
        FILLORNULLFIELDFROMDATATABLE = Ligne.Cells(DGV_FIELD).Value
    End If

End Function
```

So from there, we just have to call the function this way

Txt_City.text = FILLORNULLFIELDFROMDATATABLE(Me.dgvCustomer.CurrentRow, "City")

Comment: Good.  Consider using the `Return` keyword, instead of assigning a value to the function by name.  It will make refactoring easier, and allow non-VB-speakers to more easily understand the code you have written.